# Fade background with transparent curtain

Tags: html, css

It is quite popular question, I think.

I am looking for **crossbrowser CSS** solution for black opaque layer. Which will hide all stuff under it.

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/pb9jv/. But it is not crossbrowser. (IE 6+ is the pain in my ass).

Comment: You're relying on jQuery anyways, so you could use it to stretch out the div to the size of the window. IE6 does not play well with the `position: absolute` stretching trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this the the CSS style you apply to the fadeover (In your example : #black)

```
filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
```

EDIT : You want it to be opaque or transparent like the given example?

[Have a look at this, it does work on IE 6](http://www.pmob.co.uk/search-this/popup-fade2.htm)

Comment: what is the differents between transparent and opaque? I meen it would be, for example, 0.5 opaque or 50% transparent

Comment: @fl00r: opaque is the opposite of transparent. 100%-opaque = transparent

Comment: @Marnix, thx, but in my case it is the same. 50% transparent = 0.5 opaque :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple div and apply a background-image to it with a 1px size image of your color. Just a simple png with your black color.

```
.overlay
{
    background-image:url('myoverlaycolor.png');
}
```

It will repeat itself across the complete div.

*Edit*
Come to think of it, IE6 doesn't support png right? Maybe you could just take a look in sources like [slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2).

Comment: this is about working of transparent png in the Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1):

David is right - that is the syntax.
However your fiddle will not work in IE6 since you have no size values.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Aw4Q/
If you remove the sizing the element will not show.

Comment: so what about 100% height and 100% width? it still won't work in IE 6

Answer (score 1):

@Marnix If you use proper filters IE6 does support PNG. Try this for starters

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/pngimage.png', sizingMethod='scale');
```

Set the above filter in as a class for the span or div element containing the image and make sure the width and the height of the image are set.

Set this class also for the span or div element containing the image.

```
.PNGTrans img{
    background: transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

So the above to classes will have to be called for the parent containing the png image.

@fl00r : Have a div element with higher z-index with screen.width and screen.height as its widht and height respectively. You can either use an image or you can play with opacity filters.